# How to maintain state of filtered CursorAdapter through orientation changes?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have an application that helps users organize prescriptions. I have one listview that shows medications and I use an EditText to allow the user to filter the list. The problem I'm having is that the CursorLoader is replaced each time the orientation changes.

From what I understand, the `LoaderManager.initLoader()` function should be called in [onActivityCreated()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515799/should-we-really-call-getloadermanager-initloader-in-onactivitycreated-which). In my particular case, I don't have a fragment so I put the `initLoader()` call inside `onPostCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(MEDICATION_LOADER, null, this);
}
```

And here is the filter I'm using:

```
// Set text filter
mMedication.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        mMedicationAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }
});
```

*I removed the empty beforeTextChanged and afterTextChanged methods to shorten this.*

So, what appears to be happening (from using the debugger) is that each time I change the device orientation, `initLoader()` is called again and the entire list of medications are displayed, not just the filtered ones. Is there a way to implement `onSaveInstanceState()` to store the current filtered state of the adapter?

Or am I using the text filter wrong? Should I pass the charSequence as a Bundle argument to the loader, or create another loader that handles the text as an argument?

Comment: Dont call mMedicationAdapter.getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(s), call mMedicationAdapter.getFilter().filter() instead

Comment: @pskink what's the difference? The Adapter is a CursorAdapter, so I override getFilterQueryProvider() to requery for rows where the 'medicationName' column is similar to the input text.

Comment: because runQuery is called by a system in the background Thread

Comment: @pskink so what does filter() do differently that makes it the better option?

Comment: I already answered: your runQuery can cause ANR if it takes too long

Comment: @pskink definitely noted. I'll try to change that.

Comment: @pskink got it working without a problem. Thanks again for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is you can keep the current activity when orientation changes, Just set the Activity to handle config changes in AndroidManifest.xml:
[Android config changes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges)

e.g.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.test.MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"/>
```

Comment: You wouldn't consider this a 'hacky' solution though, would you? The only reason I ask, is because I wonder if there's a proper way to handle the loader, rather than configure the activity to maintain its state.

Comment: I am not familiar with loader though, but I think the root  is to handle the configs, I am targeting the goal of apps. It is also worth to find out how to save the state of adapter, maybe you could remember the state and just flush the UI back.

Comment: Yeah, as Jucas's answer hints at maybe I can do something with the text that's used to filter. Maybe instead of just `initLoader()` I can do a check to see if the text is empty. If it is - select all. If it's not - filter. I may as well just stick with this though until I see any reason not to. Premature optimization is the root of all evil, so say my coworkers haha.

Answer (score 0):

If your edittext was inflated through a layout file and it has an id; the framework should be automatically save its text.

You could try checking right before you attach your textwatcher, if the edittext has any text inside, then filter your list and then attach your textwatcher.

Comment: The text is saved, that was something I noticed. I will try filtering right away like that, but it seemed like a kind of hacky solution to me. I will let you know how it works.

Comment: This won't really solve my problem, as I'm setting the textWatcher in `onCreate()` so those are still being called before `onPostCreate()` so I experience the same issue.