# Native LoaderManager and Loader Retain Broken?

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-loadermanager

I am observing significant behavioral differences between the native `LoaderManager` and the version found in the support library.  Specifically with regards to the retain behavior during configuration changes.

I originally began testing this behavior because I noticed the following bug with the **support library** `LoaderManager`, and I wanted to see if it worked better with the native APIs: [Loader unable to retain itself during certain configuration change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897547/loader-unable-to-retain-itself-during-certain-configuration-change)

I have written a simple test Activity to display the issue:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String>, View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Click Me");
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        setContentView(button);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new StringLoader(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> loader, String data) {
        Log.d("LoaderTest", "Loader Finished "+loader.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String> loader) {
        Log.d("LoaderTest", "Loader Reset "+loader.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
    }

    private static class StringLoader extends Loader<String> {

        public StringLoader(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            deliverResult("Hi Mom!");
        }
    }
}
```

The `SecondActivity` in this example is just a dummy and can be anything.  It was originally added to test the Launch -> Rotate -> Return case described in the linked SO issue (which still doesn't work in the support library today).

Running this application with the `android.support.v4.FragmentActivity` and `Loader` components from `android.support.v4` as well, the behavior works as expected (minus the bug described in the link above).  One can rotate the device multiple times, and on each rotation:

- The same `LoaderManager` instance is returned from getLoaderManager()
- The same `Loader` instance is passed to `onLoadFinished()`
- `onLoadFinished()` is called immediately after each call to `initLoader()`

Now, use the example above with all "native" components for `Activity`, `LoaderManager`, `AsyncTaskLoader`, etc. and the behavior changes dramatically.  Rotate the device again a few times and:

- Now `onLoadFinished()` will only be called **every other** rotation
- When `onLoadFinished()` is called, the `Loader` instance passed in is always new
- `LoaderManager` is also a different instance during these times
- On the even rotations, the `LoaderManager` instance doesn't change and it does return the same `Loader` from `initLoader()`; however, it's `onLoadFinished()` never fires because the `LoaderManager` claims to not have been started (i.e. it's internal `mStarted` is false)

I truly hope I'm missing something quite obvious, because otherwise the behavior difference between the native `LoaderManager` versus the support library version proves to be a big problem.  Especially as developers move off the support library and back into the native APIs.

Can anyone verify this behavior or expose what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you move off the support versions? They'll always be the more consistent versions across all platforms versions and I'm sure most apps will have a reason to use something from it (be it `ViewPager` or something else).

Comment: If `ViewPager` is your only concern, there is a v13 version of the support library that doesn't include the bulk of all the other APIs.  It's a bit short-sighted to think that at some point in the future we would want to stop including back-ported code inside the APK once the minimum version supports that decision.  Unless, of course, there native implementation is broken :)

Comment: I only use `ViewPager` as an example. Nested Fragments, `PrintHelper`, `getExternalCacheDirs`, `ActionBarDrawerToggle`/`NavigationDrawer`, the entire mediarouter framework, and others are all reasons you'd continue to use the support library and with ProGuard the APK impact is much less of a concern. Also note that the v13 version of the support library includes the entire v4 support library so you aren't saving anything there.

Comment: Does the same behavior occur if you move `initLoader()` out of `onResume()` and into `onCreate()`?

Comment: Also, have you tried setting `LoaderManager.enableDebugLogging(true)`? You never know... it might help.

Comment: What API level did you find the broken behavior on?

Comment: @AlexLockwood you can try the example for yourself (which is what I was hoping people would do), the behavior doesn't seem to change regardless of where the Loader is initialized.

Comment: @louielouie This is consistent on everything from ICS to KitKat so far.